# VS2019 How to apply a partial stash after readding files

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a branch in which a stash, consisting of 10 files, 4 new, 6 modified.

I came back to that branch a week later, forgot I had the stash, readded the new files, and committed.  I want to add the rest of my stash, but git bash errors out with a simple

```
$ git stash apply --index 1
<path>/<file1> already exists, no checkout
<path>/<file2> already exists, no checkout
<path>/<file3> already exists, no checkout
<path>/<file4>  already exists, no checkout
error: could not restore untracked files from stash
```

How can I apply a partial stash pop, so I do not lose my other work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to uncommit my changes, delete the offending files, and then stash pop worked.